# Can I use Laravel api.php and web.php route files in one domain?

Tags: php, laravel

I want make my website to work like api in some route requests(return some data or update data).

Is it possible in Laravel ?

Can I use same route name in api.php and web.php files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define 2 routes with the same name in both files and you won't get any errors.

However, according to my tests it using your named route will take the route from the web.php before looking into the api.php file.

In `api.php` like this:

```
Route::get('mynamedRoute', 'HomeController@myfunction')->name('theName');
// results in http://yourdomain.com/api/mynamed-route
```

In `web.php` like this:

```
Route::get('mynamedRoute', 'HomeController@myfunction')->name('theName');
// results in http://yourdomain.com/mynamed-route
```

if you use the name in one of your blades it will take the route from `web.php`, i.e.

```
<a href="{{route('theName')}}">link</a>
// results in a link to http://yourdomain.com/mynamed-route
```

Comment: The question is about naming the route

Comment: Same for all. both are seperate.